# iPhone iOS do apps running in backgrounds generate and process notifications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

My app is downloading JSON objects in when the app enters background mode. The app converts them to core data entities. The issue that I'm running in is that I need to merge the managed object contexts for these core data entities with the main managed object context.

The way to merge these changes is through notifications:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextHasChanged:) name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:nil];


- (void)contextHasChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{

    NSLog(@"received notification with object: %@",[[notification object] description]);
    if ([notification object] == [AppUser managedObjectContext]) return;

    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(contextHasChanged:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    [[AppUser managedObjectContext] mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

For some reason my code does not receive these notifications while running in background. **Does the app continue to generate notifications while it is running in background mode?** Or is it something with the location of where/when I register for such notifications that's wrong?

Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

app continues to send notifications either in main or background. you need to take care of 
the observer should not be released during add observer and posting notification. i thnk there may some mistak in implementaion read this

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html

Comment: Thanks, I've confirmed that my code can continue to process notification based code while in background mode! (I found a class that could do this for me).

Answer (score 2):

Once you press the Home button, your app goes into suspended mode. It won't process the above notifications until you "wake" it up by tapping on its icon.

To ensure that your app continues to do its task, you need to request background task completion. The OS will then give you up to 600 seconds (10 minutes) to complete whatever task your app is doing before suspending it.

You can read more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3

Specifically, look for "Background Execution and Multitasking" in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations to what type of notifications you can receive while in the background. Also the sending of notifications is something you schedule before entering the background.

If you need to continue doing work when the app enters thebackground you should call beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler as well.

Main documentation is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Scroll down to the section in Background Execution and Multitasking